# how to pass php value to the table of of layuiadmin

Tags: php

I have a variable in PHP, and I need its value in my layuiadmin code. How can I get my variable from PHP to render table of layuiadmin framework?

I have php code that looks like this:

```
<?php
    foreach($result as $row){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row['class_id']."</td>";
      //echo "<td><a href='../class_info.php?cid=".$row['class_id']."'>".$row['class_name']."</a></td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['class_name']."</td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['teacher_id']."</td>";
      //echo "<td>".$row['student_number']."</td>";
      echo "<td><a href='./student_info.php?cid=".$row['class_id']."'>".$row['student_number']."</a></td>";
      echo "<td>".$row['reg_time']."</td>";
      $cid = $row['class_id'];
      if(isset($_SESSION[$CS_NAME.'_'.'administrator'])||isset($_SESSION[$CS_NAME.'_'."m$cid"])){
        echo "<td><a href=class_edit.php?cid=".$row['class_id'].">edit</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href=class_delete.php?cid={$row['class_id']}&getkey=".$_SESSION[$CS_NAME.'_'.'getkey'].">delete</a></td>";
    }
      echo "</tr>";
  }
  ?>
```

I have layuiadmin code in render table that I  needs  pass the variable from php to table code in layuiadmin and looks along the lines of:

```
table.render({
      elem: '#test-table-resetPage'
      ,url: layui.setter.base + 'json/table/user.js'
      ,page: {
        ,curr: 5 
        ,groups: 1 ,
        first: false 
        
      }
  ,cols: [[
    {field:'id', width:80, title: 'ID', sort: true}
    ,{field:'username', width:100, title: 'name'}
    ,{field:'sex', width:80, title: 'sex', sort: true}
    ,{field:'city', width:80, title: 'city'}
    ,{field:'sign', title: 'sign', minWidth: 150}
    ,{field:'experience', width:80, title: 'mask', sort: true}
    ,{field:'score', width:80, title: 'rate', sort: true}
    ,{field:'classify', width:80, title: 'job'}
    ,{field:'wealth', width:135, title: 'money', sort: true}
  ]]
  
});
```

});
I modify the code in the last line and it become ,

```
{field:<?php
  
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>".$row['class_id']."</td>"?>;, width:135, title: 'money', sort: true}
        // ,{field:'wealth', width:135, title: 'money', sort: true}
      ]]
      
    });
```

the table can not render and display.plz... Help Me I want " value from php to the front-end  "

Thanks